# Uniform convergence of a recursive increasing function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\phi:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ an increasing, continous function such that $\frac{1}{2}\leq\phi(x)\leq1$ for all $x$.

Let $f_0:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ an increasing function (not neccesarily continous) such that $f_0(0)\geq0$. For any $x\in[0,+\infty)$ define $f_n$ as a recursive function such that:

$$f_{n+1}(x) = \phi(x)f_n(x)+\frac{1}{ \phi(x)f_n(x)},n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Prove that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ uniformly converges in any closed interval $[0,R]$.

I tried to prove this sequence follows the Cauchy condition to get an instant uniform convergence. From what I got that
$$|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|\leq|f_{m-n}(x)-f_0(x)|+2\sum^{n}_{k = 0}|\frac{1}{f_{m-k}(x)}+\frac{1}{f_{n-k}(x)}|$$

Obviously this approach didn't seem to work. I tried to prove $f_n$ is monotone to use other theorems I have on monotone functions, getting no positive results. Which should be my approach for this problem?

Comment: I made some edits in my answer. Need still some more work!

Comment: Minor correction: you cannot have $f_0 (0)= 0$, or else you would divide by $0$.

Comment: Prove should be almost complete below.

Comment: Therefore, from where you left the right term converges to 0, therefore the converge is uniform. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some main elements for the answer. First I suppose that $\phi$ is increasing and stricty less than $1$. If you allow to have $\phi(x)=1$ the sequence $((f_n(x))$ diverges to $+ \infty$.

For $1/2 \le \phi < 1$, consider the sequence $(f_n)$ defined by the following recurrence relation:
$$f_{n+1} = \phi f_n + \frac{1}{\phi f_n} = g_\phi(f_n) \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{N}$$ where $g_\phi$ is defined as follow:
$$g_\phi:
\left|\begin{array}{lrl}
[0, +\infty & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\
y & \longmapsto & \phi y + \frac{1}{\phi y}\end{array} \right.$$

You should be able to prove following properties about $g_\phi$:

- $g_\phi$ is decreasing on $(0,1/\phi)$, has a minimum at $y = 1/\phi$ (with $g_\phi(1/\phi)=2$) and is increasing on $(1/\phi,+\infty)$
- $g_\phi$ is crossing the line $y=x$ at a single point $l_\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\phi)\phi}}$
- For $y \in (0,\frac{1}{\phi}\sqrt{\frac{1-\phi}{\phi}})$: $g_\phi(y) > l_\phi > y$.
- For $y \in (\frac{1}{\phi}\sqrt{\frac{1-\phi}{\phi}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\phi)\phi}})$: $y < g_\phi(y) < l_\phi$.
- For $y \in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\phi)\phi}},+ \infty)$: $y > g_\phi(y) > l_\phi$.
- For $y \ge 2$: $\phi \ge g^\prime_\phi(y) =\phi - \frac{1}{\phi y^2} \ge 0$
- $g_\phi(l_\phi)=l_\phi=g_\phi(\frac{1}{\phi}\sqrt{\frac{1-\phi}{\phi}})$.
- $g$ is convex.

From points above, it follows that for $x > 0$:

1. The sequence $(f_n(x))$ is monotonic from $n=1$ and for $n \ge 2$ $f_n(x) \ge g_\phi(2)$
2. The sequence $(f_n(x))$ is strictly increasing when $f_1(x) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\phi(x))\phi(x)}}$
3. The sequence $(f_n(x))$ is strictly decreasing when $f_1(x) > \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\phi(x))\phi(x)}}$
4. The sequence $(f_n(x))$ is constant when $f_1(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\phi(x))\phi(x)}}$
5. The sequence $(f_n(x))$ converges to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\phi(x))\phi(x)}}$.

when $\phi(x) < 1$, while $(f_n(x))$ diverges to $+ \infty$ when $\phi(x)=1$.

*You can then invoke the [second theorem from Dini](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8mes_de_Dini) (sorry this is in French and the English version of Wikipedia is not including this second theorem from Dini) to say that $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\phi(x))\phi(x)}}$ on all closed segments. I have to check precisely this last point however!*

However we can get rid of Dini second theorem.

By the mean value theorem, for $y \in (0,+ \infty)$ there exists $c_y \in (y,l_{\phi(x)})$ such that:
$$g_{\phi(x)}(y)-g_{\phi(x)}(l_{\phi(x)})=g_{\phi(x)}(y)- l_{\phi(x)}=g_{\phi(x)}^\prime(c_y)(y-l_{\phi(x)})$$
applying the equality to $y=f_n(x)$ you get
$$f_{n+1}(x) - l_{\phi(x)}=g_{\phi(x)}^\prime(c_y)(f_n(x)-l_{\phi(x)})$$
and for $n \ge 2$ you obtain:
$$ \vert f_{n+1}(x) - l_{\phi(x)} \vert \le \phi(x) \vert f_n(x)-l_{\phi(x)} \vert$$.
Now take any closed interval $[a,R]$ with $ 0 < a < R$. As $\phi(x)$ is supposed to be increasing and strictly less than $1$ you have $0 \le \phi(x) \le \phi(R) < 1$ for $x \in [a,R]$ hence
$$ \vert f_{n}(x) - l_{\phi(x)} \vert \le (\phi(R))^{n-2} \vert f_2(x)-l_{\phi(x)} \vert$$
for $n \ge 2$.
Proving that $(f_n(x))$ converges uniformly to the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\phi(x))\phi(x)}}$ on any compact $[a,R]$.

Comment: I already proved 1 and 4, but I'm having trouble with 2 and 3. My guess is that next I have to prove that for cases 2 and 3 the convergence point is the sup and inf respectively, therefore the function should uniformly converge. Am I correct?